# QVariant conversion doesn't recognize std::string called by my template

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qvariant

I have a function in a class header ("frame.h") that's supposed to convert a QString to a generic type, initializing it to a default value if the QString is empty, shown below.

```
template <typename T>
static void setStat(T &val, QString &temp)
{
    QVariant qv(temp);
    if (temp == "")
        val = T();
    else
        val = qv.value<T>();
}
```

When I call this (which has my only instance of a QVariant) I get the following two errors:

```
Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it 
known to Qt's meta-object system (compiling source file item.cpp)

'qt_metatype_id': is not a member of 'QMetaTypeId<T>'
```

In the file mentioned in the first error ("item.cpp"), I call setStat() once and only once, in the code below, which is in the class constructor.

```
string temp1 = "";
Frame::setStat(temp1, vec[5]);
desc = temp1;
```

It's probably worth mentioning that this is in VS2017 with the Qt extension. As I understand it, the error is telling me that std::string is an unrecognized type. Is this normal behavior? How do I fix this?

Comment: That is the usual behavior. You need to register std::string to the type system as explained in the error message.

Comment: `QVariant` works only with types known by `QMetaType`. The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @user6556709 I was under the impression that metatypes only had to be declared for custom classes since that's all I could find while looking up this error (I also thought QVariant would be able convert from QString to string since QString has a toStdString() function). I know that for custom classes, you put the metatype declaration after the class declaration, but where do I put it for standard library types?

Comment: @J. Doeling you can put it anywhere where the class is visible. For std::string I would put the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string) in an extra header included in main.cpp and qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string"); somewhere after initializing Qt in int main().

Comment: @user6556709 I've added both of those, and it does compile now, but the string is just being default initialized to "" when I call value<T>() and there's a red line under Q_DECLARE_METATYPE that says ```no instance of overloaded function "qRegisterMetaType" matches the argument list, argument types are: (const char [12], std::string *)```.

Comment: @user6556709 Thanks for your help, but I've decided to just replace all of my strings with QStrings after reading up on this some more.

Answer (score 1):

Even with registration for `QVariant`, `QString` doesn't convert freely to `QString`.

You might add overload instead:

```
static void setStat(std::string &val, QString &temp)
{
    val = temp.toStdString();
}
```

Comment: I did originally have a bunch of overloads, but I'm just trying to simplify my code since I eventually need to do something like this with several different functions. Is there any way to add a conversion method?

Comment: Actually, after thinking things through, I'm just going to replace all of my std::string class members with QString class members. Thanks for the reply, though.